# how to make text layer auto adjust width on sketch

Tags: sketch-3

I create a text layer, by default its width is just response to content, but now, I resize its width, or the group it belongs, then its width will grow like below.

[image]

For now, I have to reduce its width manually.

How can I make it reduce its width to response its actual content width automatically, or any plugin can help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Sketch documentation](https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/text/text-inspector/):

> ## Auto vs Fixed
>
> The width property (under Alignment) can be set to either Auto or
> Fixed. **When it is set to Auto, the text box’s width will expand as
> wide as possible to fit the text you entered.** When it is set to Fixed,
> it’ll wrap the text to the width set in the layer properties and place
> your text onto a new line instead.
>
> [image: Screenshot of menu with width options for a text layer]

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Thx :-) This helps!

Comment: Is there any way to make this happen on default?

Comment: If you single click with the text tool, (as opposed to click and drag) the text layer starts in *Auto*.